# If limf(x)=L (L is not 0) and limg(x)=0, then lim(f(x)/g(x)) goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If limf(x)=L (L is not 0) and limg(x)=0, then lim(f(x)/g(x)) goes to infinity?
(x approaches c)

Here do I have to use epsilon and delta proof for this question?

or Hospital's rule?

Comment: The $\epsilon-\delta$ proof is straight-forward - do you know what it means for $\lim_{x\to \infty} h(x) = +\infty$?

Comment: h(x) is not bounded as x goes to infnitiy?

Comment: Correct. Now use that fact that $f(x) \sim L \neq 0$ and $g(x) \sim 0$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Unpleasant things can happen if $g(x)$ keeps changing sign.

Comment: The problem here is I am not sure how I can use epsilon and delta to verify that f(x)/g(x) is not bounded..

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in \Bbb{R}$; let $L \neq 0$; let $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to c$; let $g(x) \neq 0$ for all suitable $x$; let $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to c$. Given any $M > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ implies
$$
||f(x)| - |L|| \leq |f(x) - L| < \frac{|L|}{2}
$$
and
$$
|g(x)| < \frac{|L|}{2M},
$$
implying that
$$
\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} > M.
$$

You may try to prove this if we are considering limits at infinity.

Comment: is last inequality equivalent to limit f(x)/g(x) goes to infinity as x goes to c?

Comment: The phrase "goes to infinity" is vague in itself; what I showed just says that the absolute value of the fraction gets arbitrarily large. Without further conditions on the behavior of $f$ and $g$, what one can say is that much. :)